# Using Gematria (גמטריא) to analyze Deuteronomy 6:4, could the value of "Echad" (אֶחָֽד) be synonymous with 13 attributes of God?

Tags: gematria-numerology

**Using Gematria (גמטריא), the word Echad (אֶחָֽד) equals 13. Why would "One" be valued as 13?**

Deuteronomy 6:4 [MT] "Hear, O Israel: The Lord is our God; the Lord is one." (שְׁמַ֖ע יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל יְהֹוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ יְהֹוָ֥ה | אֶחָֽד).

**Finding Gematria Value of "Echad" (אֶחָֽד)**

- Alef (אֶ) equals 1.
- Chet (חָֽ) equals 8.
- Dalet (ד) equals 4.

**"Echad" (אֶחָֽד) equals 1+8+4 = 13.**

Could this hidden value be synonymous with 13 attributes of God?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "could". If two words share a gematria value then I guess, sure, you could draw them together. Are you asking whether any commentators have discussed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maharal observes that the 13 "midos" (traits?) of Hashem all belong as one whole; the twelve months of the year need a 13th month to average back to one solar year; and only with Yaakov present (12+1) can his twelve sons call out *shema yisrael Hashem elokeinu Hashem ECHAD*. And we conclude the Seder with *Echad Mi Yodeya*, with the thirteen traits of Hashem concluding with His One-ness.

Comment: Address in maharal please. 13 are the 13 midot of keter following the tomer dvora